# Problem with UTF normalization in BigQuery in Javascript UDF

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to strip accents from UTF string. [Normalization function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) doesn't seem to work in BigQuery's Javascript UDF. I've tested the same function in browser and it gives me right results.

BigQuery has built in normalization function and it works fine, but why doesn't it work within Javascript UDF? Is this behavior expected? What could be the reason?

Example query:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION normAndRepl(s STRING) RETURNS STRING LANGUAGE js AS """
return s.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '')
""";

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION repl(s STRING) RETURNS STRING LANGUAGE js AS """
return s.replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '')
""";

SELECT repl(normalize('München', NFD)), normAndRepl('München')
```

The results are as expected in left column, but not necessarily in right one.

```text
f0_     | f1_
--------+--------
Munchen | München
```

Comment: The javascript documentation you linked to mentions Unicode normalization.  `ü` appears to be unicode (https://www.google.com/search?q=umlaut+u+unicode). The BQ `normalize()` function appears to behave similarly. `select normalize('München', NFD)` keeps the umlaut.

Comment: It keeps the umlaut visually but the sequence of characters becomes, well, normalized. The output should be letter `u` plus accent character. Then, the following replacement comes into place and removes accent leaving only `u`. Correct me please if I'm wrong. Besides, we can see it working well with BQ built in normalization.

Comment: This issue has been raised in this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/201771082). We cannot provide an ETA at this moment but you can follow the progress in the issue tracker and you can ‘STAR’ the issue to receive automatic updates and give it traction by referring to this [link](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue).